# Regex - Include space in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I want to permit user to enter alphanumeric and whitespace only in this input field, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I can enter alphanumeric, but unable to enter whitespace.

I tried using `/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.\\s]/g` ,

`/[^0-9a-zA-Z \.]/g`,

`/[^\w ]/g` but none of them worked. Please help.

```
app.directive('onlyAlphabets', function() { 
      return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          if(!ngModelCtrl) {
            return; 
          }

          ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                var val = '';
            }
            var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.]/g, '');
            var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');

            if(!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0,2);
                clean =decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
            }

            if (val !== clean) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
              ngModelCtrl.$render();
            }
            return clean;
          });

          element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode === 32) {
              event.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        }
      };
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow only alphanumeric and space.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/m
```

- `^` start
- `A-Z` uppercase alphabets.
- `a-z` lowercase alphabets.
- `0-9` digits.
- `\s` space
- `[A-Za-z0-9\s]+` so the above would be repeated one or more times.

To remove non-alphanumeric chars except space from the input string,

```
val.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/g, '');
```

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: @Avinash check this line in code `var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\.]/g, '');`

Comment: then it would be `val.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/g, '');`

Comment: yeah.. exactly.. but `/[^0-9a-zA-Z \.]/g` should also work right? the one user tried!

Comment: @AvinashRaj val.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/g, ''); this doesn't work.

Comment: @thm14 post a sample string along with expected output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Say I want to enter "MH SO0001 HKBU" in a text field with this directive on. Right now, the spaces don't work.

Comment: follow this `/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/m.test(input_string)`